# AirPlay audio playback with AVPlayer

Tags: objective-c, macos, audio, avplayer, macos-mojave

What is the recommended way to *programmatically* turn on (and off) AirPlay audio playback on an AVPlayer object on macOS Mojave?

I assume I need to set the right device id using `audioOutputDeviceUniqueID`, however querying CoreAudio does not give me any device ids for AirPlay devices.

- Are AirPlay devices not exposed that way anymore (this apparently [used to work](https://joris.kluivers.nl/blog/2012/07/25/per-application-airplay-in-mountain-lion/), but [not anymore](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5039701907996672))?
- What's the best way to find connected AirPlay devices?
- Is there another, better way to play an audio file via AirPlay (without UI)? Perhaps not with AVPlayer?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: IIRC, I filed a bug and Apple responded that a programmatic control was undesired, i.e., rerouting to AirPlay without using the Apple provided visual control is intentionally impossible. My opinion about Apple’s position is, let’s say, not flattering.

Comment: That is frustrating. Apple themselves does provide a programmatic way of routing Music (neé iTunes) audio to one or more AirPlay devices using AppleScript (`tell application "Music" to set current AirPlay devices to {AirPlay device "Living Room", AirPlay device "Bedroom"}`), And, actually, they offer even more information on AirPlay devices using AppleScript (e.g., you can get the MAC address and more).

Comment: Also, on iOS, you can specify the audio output using Shortcuts which ostensibly is then programmatic and not strictly visual.

Comment: My use case is to allow the user to specify the output (using an `AVRoutePickerView`) and then store that preference so subsequent launches will use the same route(s).